# How do I delete all lines in text file below certain text?

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I have a code which iterates through the entire text file searching for a specific text "[names]", and "tried" to delete all the lines below the text. I tried File.WriteAllText(INILoc, string.Empty);, but this just deletes everything in the entire text file. How do I make it so only all the lines below "[names]" gets deleted?

I have set up the iteration likes this :

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc);
bool containsSearchResul = false;
foreach (string line in lines)
    {
         if (containsSearchResul)
           {
                File.WriteAllText(INILoc, string.Empty);

           }
         if (line.Contains("[names]"))
           {
                containsSearchResul = true;
           }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It may pay to get familiar with the docs.microsoft.com website. The description for the [WriteAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) method is as follows: _Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten._ as @Prasad mentioned in his answer you are passing in string.Empty so your output is an empty file. There isn't an inbuilt method on the `File` class to do this so you'll have to "roll your own" like Prasad has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store lines before `"[names]"` text into a string variable, and when condition `(line.Contains("[names]"))` satisfy then just break the loop and write string value into the same file.

Something like,

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc); //Considering INILoc is a string variable which contains file path.
StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
bool containsSearchResul = false;

foreach (string line in lines)
    {
       newText.Append(line);
       newText.Append(Environment.NewLine); //This will add \n after each line so all lines will be well formatted

       //Adding line into newText before if condition check will add "name" into file
       if (line.Contains("[names]"))
              break;

    }

File.WriteAllText(INILoc, newText.ToString());
                        //^^^^^^^ due to string.Empty it was storing empty string into file.
```

**Note:** If you are using `StringBuilder` class, then do not miss to add `Using System.Text` in your program

Comment: Thanks! But now there is a new problem, it ended up deleting [names] too and now all the contents of the text file are pasted in one single line.

Comment: I updated my answer to cover both the scenarios which you mentioned in your comment

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I agreed with your edit suggestion, just I added seperate line of code to explain reason behind `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Also, for performence reasons, it'll be better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StreamReader` as it will give you the best performance as you don't need to read the whole file. Swap 'PATH TO INPUT FILE' with your file path and the result will be stored at the path you provide for 'PATH TO OUTPUT FILE'.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("PATH TO INPUT FILE"))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("PATH TO OUTPUT FILE"))
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(line);

            if (line.Contains("[names]"))
            {
                sw.Close();
                sr.Close();
            }
            else
            {                            
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }                        
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to write to the same file:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var sr = new StreamReader("PATH TO INPUT FILE"))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);

        if (line.Contains("[names]"))
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

File.WriteAllText("PATH TO INPUT FILE", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: What if the output and input files are the same? it gives me an error then.

Comment: @ManiacKnight Of course it gives you an error, you're trying to stream the same file twice. I've provided a solution which let you write to the same file while preserving the performance of using streams.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it delete all the lines *before* the `[names]`, not after (more exactly, write only the lines after that text). Also, any time you rewrite all the file content, and so remove all previous wrote line. It'll work as follows:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(INILoc)) // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file
{
            bool containsSearchResul = false;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {

                if (!containsSearchResul)
                {
                    writer.Write(INILoc, string.Empty);

                }

                if (line.Contains("[names]"))
                {
                    containsSearchResul = true;
                }
            }
}
```

You have another, better option to do this with `break`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(INILoc)) // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file
{
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Contains("[names]"))
                {
                    break;
                }

                writer.WriteLine(INILoc, string.Empty);
            }
}
```

But you can do this in prefered, more-readable way, by using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc);
string[] linesTillNames = lines
                          .Take( // Take just N items from the array
                              Array.IndexOf(lines, "[names]") // Until the index of [names]
                          )
                          .ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(INILoc, linesTillNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requested code I have put together modifications.

```
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc);
    //create a list to hold the lines
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    //loop through each line
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        //add current line to  ouput.
        output.Add(line);
        //check to see if our line includes the searched text;
        if (line.Contains("[names]"))
        {
            //output to the file and then exit loop causing all lines below this 
            //one to be skipped
            File.WriteAllText(INILoc, output.ToArray());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: `WriteAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> contents)` like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(INILoc);
List<string> linesToWrite = new List<string>();

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    linesToWrite.Add(line);
    if (line.Contains("[names]")) break;
}

File.WriteAllLines(INILoc, linesToWrite);
```